# JupyterLab/Jupyter Notebook not opening properly in browser

Tags: python, browser, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, config

**System:** WIN10

**System:** Microsoft SurfaceBook 2

**IDE:** ANACONDA

**Jupyter Notebook Version:** 6.1.1

**JupyterLab Version:** 2.2.6

I am having an issue with launching Jupyter Notebook and JupyterLab in Microsoft Edge. Up until recently, it was working fine and somehow now it just started attempting to an opening within a blank Microsoft Internet Explorer Window. While the notebook window in Microsoft Internet Explorer is blank I can still take the link it generates and paste it into Microsoft Edge and it finds the Notebooks on the server.

I may be missing something in the config file but can't seem to pinpoint the issue. Any light would be greatly appreciated community.

**Steps were taken:**

1. searched the net for various tutorials along with the Jupyter documentation
2. tried updating the config file as shown below

**Code:**

import Libraries
Specify what command to use to invoke a web browser when opening the notebook.
If not specified, the default browser will be determined by the `webbrowser`
standard library module, which allows setting of the BROWSER environment
variable to override it.

```
c.NotebookApp.browser = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge.exe'
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, after a week to this. The quick answer is to delete the browser that is trying to open and when Jupyter launches again then select the correct browser you wish it to use.